# Proving that $\forall n \in \mathbb N$, $\exists$ neighbourhood $V_n\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ of $(0,0)$ such that this systems has at least n solutions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Prove that, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, there exists a neighbourhood $V_n\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ of $(0,0)$ such that, for all $(a,b) \in V_n$, the system of equations: $$\begin{cases} e^x\sin y = a \\ xy = b\end{cases}$$
> Has at least $n$ solutions

I tried using the implicit function theorem and I was able to arrive at the following conclusion:

> There exists two open sets $W\subseteq \mathbb R^4$ and $V\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ such that $(0,0,0,\pi) \in W$ and $(0,0)\in V$ and there exists a function $g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R
> ^2$ of class $C^\infty$ such that: $$\begin{matrix}(a,b,x,y) \in W \\ \text{and }\\ \begin{cases} e^x\sin y = a \\ xy = b\end{cases} \end{matrix} \iff \begin{matrix}(a,b) \in V \\ \text{and }\\ \begin{cases} x = g_1(a,b) \\ y = g_2(a,b)\end{cases}\end{matrix}$$

After that, I proved using the inverse function theorem that there exists a neighborhood $K\subseteq V$ of $(0,0)$ such that the function $g|_K$ has an inverse. So, for any $(a,b)\in K\subseteq V$, we know that $x=g_1|_K(a,b)$ and $y = g_2|_K(a,b)$ are solutions of the systems of equations. Because $g|_K$ is injective, there are infinite solutions, because there are infinite points in $K$ that we can plug in $g|_K$ to get new solutions.

I'm asking this questions because the teacher asked to prove that for every $n$ there is a different neighborhood such that the system has at least $n$ solutions but I managed to find only one in which the system has infinite solutions. Is this correct or am I making some mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: It seems to me that you are misreading the question. As written the question requires you to show that for **each** pair $(a,b)$ you have at least $n$ choices for $x$ and $y$. Your argument with the injectivity of $g_1,g_2$ produces a single pair $x,y$.

Comment: You're right. How can I prove that? I have no clue how to even start @MartinArgerami

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion. After eliminating $y$ the system you wish to solve can be stated as  $ ae^{-x} = \sin (b/x)$. You could try graphing these two expressions to get some intuition about how many solutions occur as you vary $a$ and $b$.